# when clicking on tag under post wordpress doesn't show result

Tags: wordpress, search, tags, slug

I have site on wordpress, it has many posts and all they have tags, if I click on tag under post (which is two word tag, e.g. "fresh news") it searches with tag slug "fresh-news" and shows no results, how can I "ask" wordpress search with tag name (fresh news) or "ask" search to show results with tag slug?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should work the way you are expecting... what theme are you using? Can you share a link to your site so we can see the behavior ourselves?

Comment: theme is Barta, https://constructionnews.ge/%e1%83%ae%e1%83%a3%e1%83%9a%e1%83%9d-%e1%83%96%e1%83%90%e1%83%a0%e1%83%96%e1%83%9b%e1%83%98%e1%83%a1-%e1%83%92%e1%83%96%e1%83%98%e1%83%a1-%e1%83%a0%e1%83%94%e1%83%99%e1%83%9d%e1%83%9c%e1%83%a1-2/

Comment: any suggestions?